# Cannot enable http and LocalNetwork on IOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I wanna work on Local parse server but i found out that I cannot play videos that starts with "http", I've tried to enable "App Transport Security" but still not working, Any idea?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <!-- Optional: Specify minimum TLS version -->
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Please any help will be appreciated

**Edit:**  This is the code to play videos.

```
    func setupVideoPlayerWithURL(url:NSURL) {

let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:1337/parse/files/myapp/6c7c5c111a334e30cc46b5d6e79d0ab6_SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4")
    player = AVPlayer(url: url as URL)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame   // take up entire screen
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

If i use ("https" video link from internet) it works. But Any other (http) links, the video not playing or not showing up without any errors. I guess i should enable http connection but i don't know why it wont be enabled.

Comment: Define "not working" and/or post the exact error message. Is it ATS related? Also, are you running this on a device or in the simulator?

Comment: I would like to play video via "http" link but there's no error and cannot play videos from "http", I don't know what is ATS. I run this on Simulator

Comment: ATS is App Transport Security. Without further explanation of what "play video via http" and "cannot play" mean exactly and what your code does to achieve this and how you observe failures, it's unlikely others will be able to help you.

Comment: @Gereon I've just edited my answer

Comment: This link uses a ssl certificate?

Comment: @RobertoSampaio No, this localhost, I'm using Parse-Server-Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to download a video hosted on the iPhone simulator which is most likely not where the file is actually hosted. Change the URL from `localhost` to the IP of your computer which is running the Parse server, then it should find the file.

Comment: I've tried both still cannot play the video, If i use localhost on browser its working, I have tried to play this Video [link](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4) But also not working because its "http"

Comment: Can you play the localhost video in Safari on the simulator?

Comment: Yes, I've tried localhost and ip in Safari on simulator both works.